# Multiple choice ChoiceDialog?

Tags: dialog-window

I am looking for a dialog box that opens like a `ChoiceDialog` but it allows me to choose multiple items from a list and returns that list like `ChoiceDialog` returns a single chosen value.

Possible control that can act as an interface to input multiple choice could be `ListPicker`. If there are others please suggest them as well.

Please provide an example since don't know how to use `Dialog` framework of mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you also use `CheckboxBar` ?

[image]

```
Manipulate[ 
 mySelection[[n]],

 {{n, Range[4], "Choices"}, {1 -> "coffee", 2 -> "tea", 3 -> "sugar", 4 -> "cream"}, 
       ControlType -> CheckboxBar},
 TrackedSymbols :> {n}
 ,
 Initialization :> (mySelection = {"coffee", "tea", "sugar", "cream"})
 ]
```